# Cambiar formato "00 00 00.00" a decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy usando una base de datos de estrellas donde me muestra sus coordenadas, estas columnas están en formato 00 00 00.00 (hh mm ss.ms) y no he encontrado una forma de convertirlas a decimales y declararlas como "float" debido a la separación usada en el CSV (los espacios en blanco).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estrategia podría usar para declarar cada segmento como un flotante individual para así poder operarlo y convertirlo en un decimal que se reemplace en cada hilera de la columna? Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Intentaste con pandas.to_numeric()? mira la documentacion te permite convertirlo a float.

Comment: Primero intenté definir cada objeto de la columna como un float pero no funcionó, después se me ocurrió definir cada segmento como un string individual y después convertirlos a int, int, float pero no he encontrado como hacerlo apropiadamente (o si va funcionar) y por ahora estoy buscando si puedo extraer de algún modo cada segmento de la columna de manera individual, definirlas como una nueva columna una por una y después reemplazar la columna original por medio de operaciones pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: Si, he intentado con pd.to_numeric() pero me sale como resultado "Unable to parse string "00 00 00.22" at position 0", no estoy seguro pero creo que es por el tipo de separación ya que serían varios tipos de archivo (h=int, m=int, s=float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La conversión del string "hh mm ss.ff" se puede hacer con una función auxiliar.

La `to_seconds(hora)` toma una hora en el formato indicado y retorna el número de segundos y fracción.

```
def to_seconds(hora):
    horas, minutos, segundos = hora.split(" ")
    return int(horas) * 3600 + int(minutos) * 60 + float(segundos)
```

Con eso el problema se resuelve aplicando la función a toda la columna:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["01 02 03.11", "02 10 20.30"], columns=["RAhms"])
df["RAhms"] = df["RAhms"].map(to_seconds)
```

**Comprobación**

El programa de prueba

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["01 02 03.11", "02 10 20.30"], columns=["RAhms"])

def to_seconds(hora):
    horas, minutos, segundos = hora.split(" ")
    return int(horas) * 3600 + int(minutos) * 60 + float(segundos)

print(df)
df["RAhms"] = df["RAhms"].map(to_seconds)
print(df)
```

produce:

```
         RAhms
0  01 02 03.11
1  02 10 20.30
     RAhms
0  3723.11
1  7820.30
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era exactamente lo que necesitaba